# Printing .msg files client-side using VBScript in a HTML page

Tags: c#, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, vbscript

I am trying to write a feature for our SharePoint farm that lets users tick items in a document library, choose a custom action 'Print' from the ribbon and then print out the documents client side. Most of the documents print fine - (.docx, .xlsx, .pdf), as I can use ActiveXObjects with Print methods for each of these types. However, there is no ActiveXObject for Outlook that allows easy printing of .msg files. As a result, the only method I have found for printing .msg files client side through script is by vbs:

```
TargetFolder = "C:\EmailExport" 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder) 
Set colItems = objFolder.Items
For Each objItem in colItems
    objItem.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
Next
```

This works fine in a .vbs file on my local machine, but the minute I try and place it in a .html file for testing in browser, it gives me a Permission Denied error. I am not in a situation where I can modify the security levels for Internet Explorer as the company's group policies control them.

The test .html page is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript">
<!--
TargetFolder = "C:\EmailExport"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder)
Set colItems = objFolder.Items
For Each objItem in colItems
       objItem.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
Next
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have any solutions that will let me print out these .msg files client-side? I want to maintain the format that outlook prints them out in, so converting them to text files etc first isn't really an option...

Comment: Update: I get the permission denied error on the SetobjFolder = objShell.NameSpace(TargetFolder) line. I have tried different paths too, storing the files on the SharePoint site running the code and accessing via UNC paths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the Namespace method from within the browser environment for security reasons. (A webpage should never have a need to access local data directories.)  You would need to run this as a stand-alone script through the Windows Script Host.

Comment: But I need it to run in the web browser as it is generated in an aspx page. The files will not actually be stored on the local machine, they will be stored in libraries on the site somewhere. The problem is that I need to be able to print these .msg files to the local printer..

Comment: If the files are located on the web server, you shouldn't be using client-side code.  And your path would not begin with C:\.  It sounds to me like you are trying to use the wrong tool for the job.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to have a mechanism that takes various file types and prints them to a printer connected to the clients machine. For .docx, .doc, and .txt files, the following code does what I need,

<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> function printWord() { var w = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application'); var obj = w.Documents.Open("\\spsite\documents\testdocument.docx"); w.Visible = false; w.PrintOut(); } </script> </head> <body onload="javascript: printWord();"> </body> </html>

Comment: It will get a series of list items selected by the user and then process each one individually. If there is a mechanism for printing that particular file type, it will do so. .pdf files can be printed using a similiar ActiveXObject creation, but there is none like that for outlook .msg's

Comment: Then you would probably need to launch the browser with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script an it works from the HTML page, but it will only work if you use Internet Explorer as browser and the user needs to have sufficient rights on his pc and the security setting of IE need to be set to enable Active-X.

Comment: Hmm yeah but see that is the problem - as security settings are locked down via group policy I cannot change them.. Thanks Peter